# Getting all resources under a specific namespace doesn't show the deployed resource in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I deployed a simple [ResourceQuota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/) object in my k8s cluster under namespace `foo`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: my-resource-quota
  namespace: foo
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "2"
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 500Mi
    limits.cpu: "1"
    limits.memory: 500Mi
```

I can see the deployed quota under the namespace (`quota` is the shorthand name for `resourcequota`):

```
kubectl get quota -n foo
NAME                AGE   REQUEST                                                  LIMIT
my-resource-quota   5m   pods: 0/2, requests.cpu: 0/1, requests.memory: 0/500Mi   limits.cpu: 0/1, limits.memory: 0/500Mi
```

I double checked that the `ResourceQuota` is a **namespaced** object.

```
kubectl api-resources | grep quota
resourcequotas     quota        v1         true         ResourceQuota
```

The `true` in above output means it is a namespaced object.

At this moment, I have only deployed the quota object under namespace `foo`.

When I try to get all resources under namespace `foo`, I expect the output would also show me the quota object I deployed but the output shows "No resources found":

```
kubectl get all -n foo
No resources found in foo namespace.
```

It sounds like a contradictory behaviour of k8s API, why is that?

Comment: The namespace object itself is not a part of any namespace. Moreover, the persistent volumes, nodes, and other low-level resources are not a part of any namespace.

Comment: As a Community member & I also clarified that it is not possible to get NS through **kubectl get** command. I have updated my answer with the possibility of how to get **all resources** using **kubectl api-resources** and also [kubectl krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/) **plug-in** to get almost all get-all resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not true, `kubectl get all` is a false friend, it does not show everything in namespace, only `pods`, `deployemnets`, `replicaset` and `services`

Answer (score 1):

Command `kubectl get all -n <namespace>` will not show the **custom resources** running in the namespace.

As per the [Github comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151#issuecomment-402003022);

> `kubectl api-resources` enumerates the resource types available in
> your cluster. This means you can combine it with `kubectl get` to
> actually list every instance of every resource type in a namespace;
>
> ```
> kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
>   | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -n <namespace>
> ```

Also try using [kubectl krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/) plug-in and you can get almost all [get-all](https://github.com/corneliusweig/ketall) resources. Including configmap, secret, endpoints, etc..

Refer to **Abhishek Ahlawat's** post on **Studytonight** to know [How to list all resources in a Kubernetes Namespace](https://www.studytonight.com/post/how-to-list-all-resources-in-a-kubernetes-namespace#google_vignette) for more details.